# How do you keep the mobs away from your house at night?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft on creative mode, how can I keep mobs away from my home? I don't want to disable hostile mobs entirely by setting the difficulty to Peaceful, just keep them away from my house.

Comment: If you mean hostile mobs, change the gamemode to peaceful.

Comment: @TidB How to keep away, not remove entirely

Comment: If you're playing in creative mode, mobs won't attack you anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Fencing works very well in this case, as mobs cannot jump over fences, with the exceptions of the Spider.

Remember, you want a lot of lighting around your house.  Hostile mobs only spawn in dark environments, so you want plenty of lighting in and out of your house to avoid the chance of a mob spawning or getting close to you.

You can also try building lava traps, like a moat, so mobs that try to get too close end up getting burned as a punishment.

In general, it's all about lighting and keeping the area around your house open and free of darkness.

Comment: Using F7 will show blocks that will allow mobs to spawn on.  Running water and farms do not count.

Comment: Mobs now have a sense of "No, that's lava" and thus will stand at the edge of  the pool instead of jumping/falling in. They can still be pushed in however, by water, other mobs etc

Comment: @Robotnik Good point, but Drawbridges (trapdoors connected by redstone) that lead into your base,can easily be used to send mobs to their doom

Comment: @Virusboy That is not natively supported in vanilla minecraft. With default setting, F7 is used for pausing/unpasing livestream.

Comment: If you place carpet on top of fences, it can block spiders too!

Comment: @Virusboy That only works if you're running Minecraft and the NotEnoughItems mod.

Comment: A note on fencing: Mobs can't hop the fence from the level the *fence is on*.  Make sure your fence isn't within a block or two of higher elevation, and you should be fine.

Comment: If you're short on wood a 2-high dirt wall will do just as well for survival.

Answer (score 5):

Lots of torches (and other light sources) will mostly do the job.  Mobs won't spawn in light.  Surround your house with torches and you'll be fine.  Remember that each torch reaches its maximum illumination after 8 blocks (not counting elevation or inclines) when placing torches for maximum mob-repelling.

Since I notice you said you're in Creative, it might be better to use Glowstone Blocks instead of torches, since their field of light is larger, and they are just as good at discouraging Mobs from spawning.

Also remember to put a light source or a non-mob-friendly surface on your *roof*, because that is a valid mob-spawning location too.

And a wall or a fence will help tremendously in keeping mobs from wandering randomly into your territory, provided they're tall enough that they can't jump over.

Endermen might still teleport in at random though.  Besides keeping your vertical indoor space limited to less than 3 blocks, there's not much you can do to stop them.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a fence around your house and put ocelots in it creepers will stay away.  If you put tamed dogs loose around your house, you have less chance of getting skeletons close to your house, but you will soon loose your dogs. :)

Answer (score -1):

Many good answers for Minecraft can be found at the wiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/ for this you may want to look at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn

Mobs spawn based off lighting and where the player is. If you stand still mobs will randomly generate in an space where they can spawn within 120ish blocks from the player (big square 240x240 centered on the player) but no closer than 24 blocks of the player.

To prevent this from happening you need to light all of the surfaces within 120 blocks of the edges of your base. Keep in mind, if you do not find all of the caves and underground areas, they may spawn in a caves.

Answer (score -1):

Run a clocked command block of:

```
/kill @e[r=range, type =! Player]
```

Replace range with desired range.

Warning: will kill all non player entities.

Comment: He isn't using commands blocks. He's doing survival, not cheating.